# OpenTok appcelerator module using OpenTok CocoaPods

Tags: iphone, appcelerator, titanium-alloy, opentok, titanium-modules

I am trying to create Appcelerator module for OpenTok using latest OpenTok module using cocoaPods. Module gets compiled successful and module is created. But now when I try to use it sample app it gives below error:

[ERROR] : ** BUILD FAILED ** [ERROR] : The following build commands failed: [ERROR] : Ld build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/SampleApp.app/SampleApp normal x86_64 [ERROR] : (1 failure)

When I open the xcode sample project it shows below error:

ld: framework not found OpenTok clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have verified that the OpenTok framework exists in specific folder. I have properly set the below parameters in module.xcconfig file FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS= LD_RUNPATH_SEARCH_PATHS= OTHER_LDFLAGS=

Here is the module and sample code https://ufile.io/bbcbb

If somebody can point out what I am missing, would be great help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe you can use CocoaPods with a normal Appcelerator iOS module but it can be done in Titanium using Appcelerator Hyperloop.  Take a look at their documentation and let me know if you have any questions.  Thanks!

http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/iOS_Hyperloop_Programming_Guide-section-src-46253491_iOSHyperloopProgrammingGuide-CocoaPods

Comment: I think you are correct as per documentation, but I have doubt, it's not the module which gives error. Module gets compiled properly, even the module project in xcode build without error. It fails while integration in app.

Comment: That is an expected error.  The module will compile correctly but an error will occur when trying to locate that framework.   With Hyperloop, you won't have this error.

Comment: do you have sources backing your answer? I mean, where did you read that normal modules don't support pods? I've been looking for an answer for a while